# javax.persistence.PersistenceException in dynamic web application with jpa plugin

Tags: java, xml, jpa

I have my `persistence.xml` with the same name, under `src/META-INF` directory. When I call

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AdServerPU")
```

I got the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named AdServerPU
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:84)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

There are `eclipslink-2.2.0.jar` and `javax.persistence.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib`. Here is my `persistence.xml`:

[image: persistence.xml]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the "persistence.xml" _inside_ your question. It is text, so no need to post it as an image.

Comment: Did you check that the persistence.xml ends up in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml?

Comment: yes Guenther the file also in build/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: Have you added eclipse link dependency into your project?